# Login na tela de index

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, login, nav-bar

Fala galera, beleza? Então estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em ASP.NET MVC e eu tenho uma tela de login, porém eu inclui na navbar o login, onde da index o usuário poderia digitar seu e-mail e senha e clicar no botão entrar, sem precisar ser direcionado para outra página, mas isso não acontece, quando ele clica em login não funciona, apenas da um refresh na página. eu acredito que ele teria que executar o controller, mas ele não vai... o que posso fazer?

Está é minha página de login:

```
@model IEnumerable<Tribus.Models.Pessoa>
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h1>
            <p class="text-center"><b>Entrar no aplicativo</b></p>
        </h1>
        <hr />
        <h3 class="text-center">@ViewBag.Error</h3>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <h1><b>Bem vindo a Tribus</b></h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">
                Email
            </label>
            <div>
                <div class="col-md-10 ">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">
                Senha
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

está é minha página _layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
@*NÃO MEXER EDITADO POR GABRIEL*@
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @{
        Tribus.Models.Pessoa pessoa = Tribus.Repositorios.Funcoes.GetUsuario();
        string nome;
        int acesso = 0;
        int id = 0;


        if (pessoa == null)
        {

            <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Tribus", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })

                        @Html.ActionLink("Login", "Logar", "Publico", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                    </div>
                    <center>
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">

                            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                                @*@using (Html.BeginForm())
                                    {
                                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" autocomplete="on" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="password" id="senha" class="form-control" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-default" />
                                @*}*@
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </center>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        else if (pessoa != null)
        {
            id = pessoa.PessoaID;
            nome = pessoa.Nome;
            <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Tribus", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sair", "Logoff", "Publico")</li>
                            @*<li>@nome</li>*@
                            Bem vindo @nome
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p class="text-center">&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - Tribus- Oruam</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/inputmask")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

e esta é minha página inicial

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<div class="">
    <h1>Tribus</h1>
    <p class="lead text-justify">Apresentação do aplicativo</p>

    <p class="lead text-center">Não é cadastrado? Cadastra-se!</p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <p><a href="~/Musico/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sou Músico </a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <p><a href="~/Usuario/Create" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sou Usuário</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

este é o Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Tribus.Models;
using Tribus.Repositorios;

namespace Tribus.Controllers
{
    public class PublicoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Publico
        public ActionResult Logar()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Logar(string email, string senha)
        {
            if (Funcoes.AutenticarUsuario(email, senha) == false)
            {
                ViewBag.Error = "Nome de usuário e/ou senha inválida";
                return View();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        public ActionResult AcessoNegado()
        {
            using (Context c = new Context())
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        public ActionResult Logoff()
        {
            Tribus.Repositorios.Funcoes.Deslogar();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso daqui está muito errado (não me entenda mal):

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
    @*@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()*@
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required="required" autocomplete="on" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" id="senha" class="form-control" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" required="required" autocomplete="off" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-default" />
    @*}*@
</form>
```

Seu `form` não está realizando nada, pro assim dizer.

Remova o `form` em HTML e altere para Razor, como na sua tela de login, desta forma:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Logar", "Publico", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h1>
            <p class="text-center"><b>Entrar no aplicativo</b></p>
        </h1>
        <hr />
        <h3 class="text-center">@ViewBag.Error</h3>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <h1><b>Bem vindo a Tribus</b></h1>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">
                Email
            </label>
            <div>
                <div class="col-md-10 ">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2">
                Senha
            </label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Em resumo, a falta desta parte que é o seu problema:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm("Logar", "Publico", FormMethod.Post))
```

Com isso, o seu `form` irá ser da seguinte forma:

```
<form action="/Publico/Logar" method="post">
```

Comment: Obrigado Randrade! resolveu meu problema!!